# How to synchronize from SQL Express 2008 to SQL Server 2008?

Tags: c#-3.0, microsoft-sync-framework, sql-server-2008-express

I have an app the runs at the store level extracting data out of a POS system. This app asks the POS system for data which in return produces some .DBF files.  The app loads the DBFs in memory and saves it to SQL Server 2008 Express at the store level.  This happens at 3 different stores.

I have been looking into the Microsoft Sync Framework, but have not come across any good examples of how to sync tables in one direction only, from each of the stores into a single database at the corporate level.

The data at each one of the stores is being managed by the app(delete, update, insert).

Does anyone know a good article, that I could read about synchronizing SQL data?

Thank you.

Comment: duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5072065/microsoft-sync-framework-2-1-change-tracking-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 2):

Try the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/DTS_SQLExpress.aspx