# Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 + Change Tracking in Sql-Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework

When I provision a scope for synchronization in an SQL 2008 database like this:

```
SqlSyncScopeProvisioning sqlServerProv = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlServerConn, myScope);
if (!sqlServerProv.ScopeExists(scopeName))
{
   sqlServerProv.Apply(); // Apply the scope provisioning.
}
```

i see a bunch of change tracking tables, stored procedures and triggers created.
Why is this not using the "Change Tracking" feature of SQL 2008, which is much cleaner and everything gets tracked behind the scenes?
I thought that the "Change Tracking" feature of SQL 2008 was designed precisely to simplify these scenarios.

Now turning the question around: Is there a way to do a 2-way synchronization between two SQL Server 2008 databases just using Change Tracking in both of them instead of provisioning the triggers/auxiliary tables ?

Comment: FYI, some useful conversation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/uklaunch2007ado.net/thread/0b3e7150-fa76-4c41-97b7-e12d6f3f6713

Comment: This is also helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305322.aspx

Comment: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4835

Comment: This one gets close: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/uklaunch2007ado.net/thread/33212eeb-1215-40e1-969c-43019919e101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Syncing SQL Server 2008 Databases over HTTP using WCF & Sync Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1656652/23697)